# Samsung Gear VR - is it possible to develop in C++?

Tags: android, c++, oculus, gear-vr

Is it possible to develop for `Samsung Gear VR` in `C++` only and possibly combine it with Qt? According to http://www.gearvrf.org/ there's a Gear VR native library, but is it `supported` in any way (samples, documentation..) ?

Comment: A perfectly valid answer to your question would be "Yes." (or "No."). If someone answered your question by simply saying "Yes.", would that be helpful to you (or to others finding this question in the future)? I suggest that you edit your question to reflect what you _really_ want to know.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are actually two questions:

Is it possible to develop for Samsung Gear VR in C++ only?

Yes, definitely, but I would prefer Oculus native mobile SDK over your mentioned framework. Because at current stage, it is really Oculus who are pushing the software development forward, you know John Carmack, right? And he also brings a lot engineering friends from ID software to Oculus too, which you will come across a lot when reading the code distributed with the SDK.

https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/latest/concepts/book-native/

Combine with QT?

I don't think there is any benefit now, if what you need is to build menus, buttons, UI elements like this. UI elements are very different in VR world, which the graphic is all about a 3D based world. And I think if you are following the native development path, you can only count on some preliminary UI support from Oculus too. Again, you can only get help by reading the source code in the mobile SDK from Oculus.