# Gear VR Framework (GearVRF): add elements in front of a 360 video

Tags: java, android, gear-vr

I'm getting into the wonderful world of VR using the Samsung Gear VR and the Gear VR Framework (gearvrf).

My goal is to implement a quick menu on top of a playing 360 video: have a few icons and a frame that will go around the selected one.

I already successfully implemented and modified the gvr-360video example from https://github.com/gearvrf/GearVRf-Demos/tree/master/gvr-360video and in more details this particular file: https://github.com/gearvrf/GearVRf-Demos/blob/master/gvr-360video/app/src/main/java/org/gearvrf/gvr360video/Minimal360Video.java

As I'm fully aware I have very little background in VR and 3D in general, I was therefore wondering about the specific elements of the gearvrf that I should use to implement my functionality?

Also, is it possible to detect the moment where the user removes the gearVR?

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer about [building UI for GearVR using QT and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482139/samsung-gear-vr-is-it-possible-to-develop-in-c/35493120#35493120) applys to your question too.

I bet questions like this will still keep coming a lot, until a lightweight UI element focused 3D framework pop up. Oculus provides a UI framework in its mobile SDK, but it is still too "low level" and requires quite an understanding of 3D programming, hard to develop and debug.

Frankly speaking, building UI for GearVR(and other VR devices as well) is quite a headache now, especially if you do not have any 3D programming experiences.

> Also, is it possible to detect the moment where the user removes the gearVR?

Yes, check the source code here, which is a copy from Oculus mobile SDK.

[VrApi.h](https://github.com/SoylentGraham/VRLib/blob/master/jni/VrApi/VrApi.h)

Looks for the methods named "ovr_EnterVrMode" and "ovr_LeaveVrMode", it should be there in GearVRF too.